# Openal buffer play only if filled with for cycle

Tags: c++, c, openal

I'm getting crazy trying to solve this strange behavior.
I successful created a OpenAL buffer to queue waves and so play it:

```
static ALuint           snd_buffer  =0;

#define NUM_BUFFERS 10
static ALuint source, buffers[NUM_BUFFERS];

static float            pitch       = 1.0f;
static ALCdevice *      my_dev      = NULL;
static ALCcontext *     my_ctx      = NULL;
```

...

```
alGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS,buffers);
for (i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++) {//EXPERIMENTAL (chaned i=0 to i=1)
    buffers[i]=load_wave(wavFile);
}
```

Once filled the buffer, I can successful play, all is ok and I can hear the queue that loop the wave 10 times:

```
alSourcePlay(source);
```

So far all is working fine, this obviously is only a test function, so I tried to replace for cycle and fill buffer "manually":

```
buffers[0]=load_wave(wavFile);
```

or

```
buffers[1]=load_wave(wavFile);
buffers[2]=load_wave(wavFile);
buffers[3]=load_wave(wavFile);
buffers[4]=load_wave(wavFile);
```

...

If I fill the buffer with for cycle all is working well, but if I try to feel buffer with buffers[whatever]=load_wave(wavFile) symply doesn't work, I can't hear nothing.

Comment: But there is difference between `0 to 10` and `0 to 4` is the actual data getting loaded from 5? We don't see buffers getting filled from `buffer[5]`

Comment: Is only a test, I tried to fill 0 up to 10, only 0, 0 up to 5 but doesn't work. I understand that it's not mandatory to feel up all the buffer queue, right? I should be able to fill a part of the buffer so play it, right? Even so, filling buffer from 0 to 10, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself, 
I'm posting solution for other people. The problem was in

> alSourceQueueBuffers(source, NUM_BUFFERS, buffers);

the correcty way is pass the real user buffer usage instead all NUM_BUFFERS to alSourceQueueBuffers function